# Excluding rows from table border, chessboard HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table, row, border

I was trying to create a chessboard (HTML/CSS) with tables. And I'm having trouble with table borders. I would like only the board to have a border, with row numbers and column letters excluded.

How can I do that?

```css
table {
  border-bottom: solid 2px;
  border-left: solid 2px;
  border-right: solid 2px;
  border-top: solid 2px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr {
  text-align: center;
}
.black-square {
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.white-square {
  background-color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" ; cellspacing="0" ;>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
    <td>g</td>
    <td>h</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square">
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square">
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square">
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is that you can give border: 1px solid #000; to the `.white-square` and `.black-square` and reduce `1px` from `height` and `width` of those.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/9akqpu50/1/)

```
.white-square,
.black-square
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 49px;
    height: 49px;
}
```

Comment: @Isaac Is this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

First of, you have a stray `<tr>` in your code between your coordinates and your board, so make sure to remove that.

You can stack pseudo-selectors to target only the `td`s you need.

We want a border underneath the coordinates at the top. That is, the `td`s of the first row, except the first one and the last one. The css-rule for that is:

```
tr:first-child td:not(:last-child):not(:first-child){
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

Colour chosen so that it's clear what we're targeting.

By using three similar selectors we can target the four borders of the board.

```css
table {
  border-bottom: solid 2px;
  border-left: solid 2px;
  border-right: solid 2px;
  border-top: solid 2px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr {
  text-align: center;
}
.black-square {
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.white-square {
  background-color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
tr:first-child td:not(:last-child):not(:first-child){
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
} 
tr:last-child td:not(:last-child):not(:first-child){
    border-top: 5px solid fuchsia;
} 
tr:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) td:first-child{
    border-right: 5px solid lime;
}
tr:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) td:last-child{
    border-left: 5px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" ; cellspacing="0" ;>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
    <td>g</td>
    <td>h</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square">
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square">
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square">
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td class="white-square"></td>
      <td class="black-square"></td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```